# How to filter for named branches with a partial name match in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I use the following search expression to find all the heads which aren't closed in our mercurial repository:

```
head() and not closed() and not branch('default')
```

However, I have a convention to name feature branches as `fb-(target-release)-(feature-name)` and I'd also like to filter for the named branches which contain `fb` **at the beginning of their name**. Is this possible without piping the output to another application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in the `branch` expression. From `hg help revset`:

```
  "branch(string or set)"
  All changesets belonging to the given branch or the branches of the
  given changesets.

  If "string" starts with "re:", the remainder of the name is treated as a
  regular expression. To match a branch that actually starts with "re:",
  use the prefix "literal:".
```

So to match `fb-` at the beginning of the name:

```
head() and not closed() and not branch('default') and branch('re:^fb-')
```